# What impact on the index storage size does overprovisioning of varchar types have?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Does over-provisioning `varchar` columns (as in using `varchar(100)` to store values from 1 to 10 characters long vs using `varchar(10)`) have any impact on the index storage size and if yes than why?

I recall reading a Q/A here about this but cannot find it using any of the terms which come to mind.

I do not care about memory grants or plans - only about the physical storage of the indices on such data.

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162113/would-using-varchar5000-be-bad-compared-to-varchar255/162117#162117

Comment: I cannot edit questions or comment from where I am but I do not care about memory grants or plans - only about the physical storage of the indices on such data.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: From only a storage perspective, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Variable length columns only *store* the actual data present in the column.  In other words, the defined length of a varchar column has no bearing on the amount of physical storage allocated.

However, querying the data requires a memory allocation that is commonly calculated to be the number of rows expected multiplied by 50% of the defined column size.  So, if you define a column as varchar(500), but only store 50 bytes in the column,  you're wasting 200 bytes of RAM per row *in memory*.