# Mssql subquery inside a substring

Tags: sql-server, subquery, substring

I need to remove the last character of my subquery but I cannot figure out how to reference my subquery in the subselect as I need the length of it.

The subselect collects all rows and converts them into a single string by appending them with a separator ";".

This is what I need:

```
(SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT 
                    d1.name +'; '
    FROM   
                    data1 d1 
                    inner join data2 d2
                    on d1.id = d2.id
    WHERE   
                    d1.id = dOfOutterSelect.id 
    ORDER BY
                    d1.CreatedOn FOR XML PATH('') 

    ),
LENGTH(),1)) 

As "Row name",
```

Comment: if you are on SQL Server 2017+ you can use STRING_AGG function to concatenate rows instead of this construction with FOR XML PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `STUFF(...)` T-SQL function to strip the last character off.  First `REVERSE` the string from the query results, then use `STUFF`, then `REVERSE` the result again.

Like this:

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE('this is my string'), 1, 1, ''))
```

The result looks like:

| Results |
| --- |
| this is my strin |

Here's the Microsoft Docs pages for [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) and [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql).

Actually, looking at your query more closely, you can refine it slightly to eliminate the use of the `REVERSE` function.  Take the example below, where I'm concatenating the names of all the columns in the database with a semi-colon separator.

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT N'; ' + c.name
    FROM sys.columns c
    FOR XML PATH (N'')
    ), 1, 2, N'');
```

I add the semi-colon at the *start* of the string, then simply use `STUFF` to replace the first 2 characters with "nothing".

So the results look like:

| Results |
| --- |
| Column1; Column2; Column3 |

Newer versions of SQL Server (2017+) support the use of the `STRING_AGG` aggregate which can significantly simplify this kind of query.  To get the same output as my query above, using `STRING_AGG`, you'd write it like this:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), c.name), N'; ')
FROM sys.columns c;
```

There is `CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ...)` wrapped around the `c.name` column to coerce the `STRING_AGG` function into using a string of sufficient length to contain all the column names in my database.  If you leave that out, SQL Server reports an error:

> Msg 9829, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: The `N` prefix on a string indicates to SQL Server that the string is of type nchar or nvarchar, which prevents an implicit conversion when concatenating to nvarchar/nchar/sysname columns (in this case, `sys.name` is a `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`).  Also, see [Write differences between varchar and nvarchar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36081).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have another problem. This does not work when "; " is mixed with integer. I tried the following without success

```
(SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT 
                    '; ' +  CONVERT(INT,
                            CASE
                            WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), d1.numbericData)) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),c.numbericData) 
                            ELSE 0 END)  
    FROM   
                    data1 d1 
                    inner join data2 d2
                    on d1.id = d2.id
    WHERE   
                    d1.id = dOfOutterSelect.id 
    ORDER BY
                    d1.CreatedOn FOR XML PATH('') 


), 1, 2, N''))
´´´
```

Comment: Found a solution: CONCAT('; ', d1.data)

Comment: Please do not add details or another question in the "Your Answer" box.  Either add these details to your qustion at the top via the [edit] function, or ask an entirely new question via https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: The reason this "doesn't work" is because you're attempting to append an int to a string.  This will result in an error reported by SQL Server.